# How to use the change record get by IHTMLChangeLog?

Tags: html, browser

I think the documentation of IHTMLChangeLog in MSDN is not complete.

Could any one tell me how to use the IHTMLChangeLog?

and how could I use and parse the change record(pbBuffer) get in IHTMLChangeLog::GetNextChange() ?